# Using a counter to find multiple occurences on same day from ID & date

Tags: sas

I am trying find when a person has multiple occurences on the same day & when they do not.
My data looks something like this

```
data have;
input id date ;
datalines ;
1 nov10
1 nov15
2 nov11
2 nov11
2 nov14
3 nov12
4 nov17
4 nov19
4 nov19
etc...;
```

I want to create a new variable to show when an occurence happens on the same day or not. I want my end rseult to look like

```
data want;
input id date occ;
   1 nov10  1
   1 nov15  1
   2 nov11  2
   2 nov11  2
   2 nov14  1
   3 nov12  1
   4 nov17  1
   4 nov19  2
   4 nov19  2
   etc...;
```

THis is what I tried but it is not working for each date instead only doing it if the date repeats on the first. Here is my code

```
data want ;
set have ;
by id date;
if first.date then occ = 1;
else occ = 2;
run;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your IF/THEN logic is just a complicated way to do

```
occ = 1 + not first.date;
```

Which is just a test of whether or not it is the first observation for this date.

Looks like you want to instead test whether or not there are multiple observations per date.

```
occ = 1 + not (first.date and last.date) ;
```

Comment: Thank you! That output exactly what I wanted.